# Firebase do not collect opens and conversion data of push notifications for ios part of Flutter app

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use FCM in Flutter project, push notifications are well received and processed on Android and iOS. But for iOS opens and conversions data do not collect in Cloud messaging section of Firebase console. How can I fix it?
[image]

Comment: Can you try follow this setup: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration ? There are additional steps need to get push notifications working on iOS

Comment: I have completed all the points except for the option with images, but all the same, the data in the firebase console is not collected